# Checking mailbox attribute and adding value if null

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want to check an attribute of all mailboxes in an organisation; if the value is null then I want to add an attribute (email address)

```
get-mailbox -Organization test.me.net |
if (-ForwardingSmtpAddress -eq {})
{
Set-Mailbox -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSmtpAddress admin@test.me.net
}
```

the error message I am getting is...

The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
 of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Scripts\smtpaddress.ps1:2 char:3
+ if <<<<  (-ForwardingSmtpAddress -eq {})
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (if:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

any ideas how I can resolve this?

Thanks for reading, Colm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Filter parameter to get mailboxes that do not have a value in the ForwardingSmtpAddress property, pipe the result to Ste-Mailbox and set the DeliverToMailboxAndForward and ForwardingSmtpAddress parameters. Keep in mind that all mailboxes will forward emails to the admin mailbox.:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit me.net/test -Filter {ForwardingSmtpAddress -eq $null} | Set-Mailbox -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSmtpAddress admin@test.me.net
```

Comment: many thanks to Shay
just a typo with a ) instead of a }; works great!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do an if on each if you pipe it to a For-Each like this:

```
get-mailbox | % {
if ($_.ForwardingSmtpAddress -eq {})
{
*Do something*
}
}
```

But you should probably just use a filter and pipe the results into a set-mailbox command (the question mark stands for Where-Object):

```
get-mailbox | ? {$_.ForwardingSMTPAddress -eq {}} | Set-Mailbox......
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a script written for enabling retention policy for those who have none applied.

`Get-Mailbox -filter {retentionpolicy -eq $null} | Set-Mailbox -retentionpolicy "120DayRetention Policy"`

Worked like a charm.